# Recursively expand a string array with all possible combinations

Tags: php, arrays, string, recursion

I've got a problem to resolve: expanding a string array that can contain strings without a comma and strings with a comma: if an element with comma is found, that string has to be splitted and recursively combined with all the prev and next elements in the array ( that can contain, or not, a comma ).

Consider this input string array:

```
$input = Array ( 'hello', 'world', 'we,I', 'are,am', 'alive' );
```

This should get translated to:

```
$output = Array (
   'hello world we are alive',
   'hello world we am alive',
   'hello world I are alive',
   'hello world I am alive'
);
```

The function I've came up to write ( bugged! ) is this one:

```
    /* bugged! don't consider it as working code! */
function recursiveExpandCommaDelimitedStringsArray ( $input_strings_array, $depth = 0, $this_string = '' ) {

    ksort ( $input_strings_array, SORT_NUMERIC );
    $return = Array ();
    $subarray = $input_strings_array;
    foreach ( $input_strings_array as $i => $string ) {
        unset ( $subarray[$i] );
        if ( strpos ( $string, ',' ) !== false ) {
            $substrings = array_filter ( explode ( ',', $string ), 'strlen' );
            foreach ( $substrings as $substring ) {
                $subarray[$i] = $substring;
                $return[] = recursiveExpandCommaDelimitedStringsArray ( $subarray, ++$depth, $this_string );
            }
        }
        else $this_string .= $string . ' ';
        $subarray = $input_strings_array;
    }

    if ( $depth === 0 ) return $return;
    else return $this_string;
}
```

Once the solution is found, I will update the code in this question.
Thank you!

Comment: Are these hard requirements, or do you have some room to move? for example, to the elements *have* to be separated by commas, or can you change how the function takes in the input?

Comment: @WilliamPerron thank you for your comment, I have room to move, in the sense that I am in control of the "builder function" of the input array. Only problem is that, for the sake of simplicity in the builder's function, I have to include the elements in that way, in other words, concatenate or add a new element based on an unknown state of the origin data "above". Anyway, I can for example do $input = Array ( 'one', Array ( 'two', 'three' ), 'four', Array ( 'five', 'six' ) ); if that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily solved using a combination of `array_reduce` and `array_map`. A quick a dirty solution would be:

- Start with an array with one solution: `['']`
- For each word of your original array, append the word to each solution on your solutions array
- If you find a word with a comma, explode it and create a new solution for each word in the exploded array
- Repeat until you reach the end of the array
- You will now have all possible combinations in your solutions array

Here it is in (not so elegant) code:

```
<?php
$words = ['I', 'am', 'a', 'happy,sad', 'person,cat,dog', 'looking', 'for', 'a,one', 'book,pillow,thing,treat'];

$phrases = array_reduce($words, function($result, $word) {
    if (strpos($word, ',') === false) {
        return array_map(function($r) use ($word) {
            return "$r $word";
        }, $result);
    }

    $forkedWords = explode(",", $word);
    $newResults = [];
    foreach($forkedWords as $fWord) {
        $newResults[] = array_map(function($r) use ($fWord) {
            return "$r $fWord";
        }, $result);
    }

    return array_reduce($newResults, 'array_merge', []);
}, ['']);

var_dump($phrases);
```